# Loop that appends each letter of the alphabet together

Tags: javascript

I am new to programing and am struggling with a homework question. 
The question is as follows:

Write a “for” loop that appends (string concatenation) each letter of the alphabet together and after the “for” loop has finished running, logs the output to the console. (hint: you should have one long string of “abcdefg”, etc.)

I tried declaring a variable "abcdefgh...." and using the pop method to remove each letter but was told that is not the correct way. I talked with my professor and she told me the code should consist of a large loop body consisting of ifs or switch cases.

```
let getAlpha = "";
for (i = 0; i <= strAlpha.length; i++){
    getAlpha.pop();
    console.log(getAlpha);
}
```

I think I'm very far off the actual answer, but am not sure how to get there.

Comment: What is the input?  Meaning, from where are you getting the characters initially?  Are you supposed to start with an array of individual characters and output a concatenated string?  Or something else?

Comment: I believe I'm supposed to start with an empty string and then each loop iteration add another letter of the alphabet, then concatenate those strings, then log everything in the console.

Comment: I don't see the need for if/else inside the loop body, if you just want to concatenate the alphabet to a string. This can be trivially done by iterating over the ASCII code range from A to Z (i.e. 65 to 90), turning each numeric ASCII code into their respective character and appending that character to a string. You can use the `String.fromCharCode()` method for turning an ASCII code into a character

Comment: @tiguchi is correct. Have you provided a complete enough example for us to effectively help you out? It doesn't seem necessary to use "ifs or switches." Are there conditions that you are supposed to take into account as well (like, take every other letter, every fifth letter, etc)?

Comment: as i see the assignment, you should take an empty string and add in a loop all characters from `'a'` to `'z'`. the main problem is to take the next letter.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```js
    let getAlpha = "";
    for (let i = 65; i <= 90; i++){
        getAlpha += String.fromCharCode(i);
    }
    console.log(getAlpha);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the block of code that I ended up using. I'm sure it's not the most efficient code but it's what my instructor was looking for in this situation.

```
let alphaString = "";
for (let i = 0; i <= 26; i++) {
switch(i) {
    case 0: 
        alphaString += "a";
        break;
    case 1:
        alphaString += "b";
        break;
    case 2:
        alphaString +="c";
        break;
    case 3:
        alphaString +="d";
        break;
     case 4:
        alphaString +="e";
        break;
    case 5:
        alphaString +="f";
        break;
    case 6:
        alphaString +="g";
        break;
     case 7:
        alphaString +="h";
        break;
    case 8:
        alphaString +="i";
        break;
    case 9:
        alphaString +="j";
        break;
    case 10:
        alphaString +="k";
        break;
    case 11:
        alphaString +="l";
        break;
    case 12:
        alphaString +="m";
        break;
    case 13:
        alphaString +="n";
        break;
    case 14:
        alphaString +="o";
        break;
     case 15:
        alphaString +="p";
        break;
    case 16:
        alphaString +="q";
        break;
    case 17:
        alphaString +="r";
        break;
    case 18:
        alphaString +="s";
        break;
    case 19:
        alphaString +="t";
        break;
    case 20:
        alphaString +="u";
        break;
    case 21: 
        alphaString +="v";
        break;
    case 22:
        alphaString +="w";
        break;
    case 23:
        alphaString +="x";
        break;
    case 24:
        alphaString +="y";
        break;
    case 25:
        alphaString +="z";
        break;
}
console.log(alphaString);}
```